# MySql stored procedure in Node not working

Tags: mysql, node.js, stored-procedures

I am using Node JS, Express and Mysql. I created stored procedures and calling the stored procedure from within Mysql yields the correct results, but calling it from Node yields undefined values.

My stored procedure:

DELIMITER //

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Read_Categories_SP()
BEGIN
    SELECT CategoryID, CategoryName
    FROM Categories
    ORDER BY CategoryName;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Within MySql Workbench running this procedure gives me:

2   ARIA
1   IT
3   Workshop

In Node:

```
    // This does not work
    const [result1] = await mysqldb.pool.query('CALL Read_Categories_SP');
    
    // This works
    const [result2] = await mysqldb.pool.query('SELECT * FROM Categories');
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a problem with NodeJS. You don't need to call it like:

```js
const [result1] = await mysqldb.pool.query('CALL Read_Categories_SP');
```

Change it to:

```js
const result1 = await mysqldb.pool.query('CALL Read_Categories_SP');
```

That should work. You will be able to access the categories using `result1[0], ...`

And also, have a proper try-catch mechanism to handle errors.

Edit: It seems a small adjustment is needed to access the result of MySQL query -

```js
const [rows] = await mysqldb.pool.query('CALL Read_Categories_SP()');
const result1 = rows[0];
```

By assigning rows[0] to result1, you will have the first row of the result set available for further processing.

Comment: Thank you, but that does not work. It still gives undefines values.

Comment: let me check after getting back home, I might have missed something

Comment: Thank you. It is just strange that it works when I use the query itself, but not when I use the stored procedure.

Comment: added an edit to the answer